# undefined reference to a static library

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, target-link-libraries, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, I'm having a lot of trouble with this one: (ros fuerte, ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

I'm working on a C++ package that uses a C library libccv.a. When linking, I am getting this error:

```
undefined reference to 'ccv_enable_default_cache()'
```

and more undefined references to the stuff from the library

libccv.a comes with a header file ccv.h and it depends on libjpeg and libpng.

here is the relevant part of the CMakeLists.txt

```
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
rosbuild_add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/TDetector.cpp src/TRecognizer.cpp src/${PROJECT_NAME}.cpp)
FIND_LIBRARY(ccv libccv.a PATHS ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}))
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
FIND_LIBRARY(jpeg libjpeg.a PATHS usr/lib)
FIND_LIBRARY(png libpng.a PATHS usr/lib)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${ccv} ${jpeg} ${png})
```

the library is in /lib folder of my project. everything else (source and headers) is in /src. I also tried the `link_directories` way instead of find_library, without success. I believe the linker finds the library because there is no `cannot find` message

I read some resources on rosbuild but I can't make it work. What am I doing wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62598/undefined-reference-to-a-static-library/) by [vonovak](https://answers.ros.org/users/4872/vonovak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2013-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was in linking a C library into a C++ program.

The solution was to wrap ccv.h into ccv.hpp which looks as follows

```
extern "C"
{
#include "ccv.h"
}
```

(add include guard as you like)

Then, I included ccv.hpp in the sources.
If you want to know more, google `name mangling`.

And second, use find_package command to load the  jpeg and png libraries.

---

Originally posted by [vonovak](https://answers.ros.org/users/4872/vonovak/) with karma: 88 on 2013-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [redheli](https://answers.ros.org/users/3571/redheli/) on 2015-12-01**:
Thx vonovak! it works

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the issue is that you have specified the full name of `libccv.a` and should instead use the shortened `ccv` form.

Also, according to the [cmake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command:find_library), `find_library` won't display an error message if the library is not found.  Try this, instead:

```
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
rosbuild_add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/TDetector.cpp src/TRecognizer.cpp src/${PROJECT_NAME}.cpp)

FIND_LIBRARY(ccv ccv PATHS ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}))
if (CCV)
  message(STATUS "Library(CCV) found in ${CCV}")
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Library (CCV) not found")
endif()

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
FIND_LIBRARY(jpeg libjpeg.a PATHS usr/lib)
FIND_LIBRARY(png libpng.a PATHS usr/lib)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${ccv} ${jpeg} ${png})
```

You should probably be using `find_package(jpeg REQUIRED)` and `find_package(png REQUIRED)` instead, but what you have listed above will probably work also.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-05-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vonovak](https://answers.ros.org/users/4872/vonovak/) on 2013-05-13**:
Thanks, this looks better. However, I am getting "Library (CCV) not found", even though the path provided is correct. Changing between libccv.a and ccv doesn't help. Neither does moving the library to different location. Any ideas? Thanks